# How do I get the card back for beating Heroic mode in the Curse of Naxxramas?

Tags: hearthstone

As the title suggests, what conditions must be met for me to be awarded with the new card back?

I heard it was from beating the first wing in heroic mode. I managed to beat them but there is no sign of a new card back. Do I have to wait for all of the wings to come out and beat the heroic mode on all of them to get it or is it something entirely different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to complete all 5 wings on heroic mode to unlock the new card back.

[image]

[Source](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Card_back#Not_yet_available)

> Completing Naxxramas on Heroic mode (Quest: The Fall of Naxxramas)

Answer (score 1):

You don't get it from beating the first wing on heroic.

You have to beat all 5 wings on heroic mode.